# Check if a number belongs to a list

Tags: powershell

I want ot verify if the user entered number belongs to a predefined list, but the `-contains` operator behaves slightly different than I expected:

```
0 -contains 0.
True
```

The list is generated with the command `(get-disk).number`. What do I have to do to get `False` for the input `0.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should wrap the output of `(get-disk).number` with `@()` to force the list to be an array. Then, ensure its an array of strings using a cast. Finally, pass the number you want to check using a string:

```
[string[]]$list = @((get-disk).number) # my list contains only 0

$list -contains "0." # False
```

The double `0.` is eqal to the int `0` is equal to the string `"0"` thus you have to pass it as a string.

Comment: 0., 00, 000 etc are still returning true.

Comment: I missed the part with the dot, sorry. Answer is updated.

Comment: @PawełDyl no, this doesn't work since the return value from get-disk is an array of UInt32 and the string "0." will get converted to 0

Comment: You can also use `(get-disk).number.ToString() -contains "0."`